# wso2 IS sp1 session management contd

Tags: session, wso2, session-timeout, wso2-identity-server

I would like to know whether session data persistence

```
<SessionDataPersist>
        <Enable>true</Enable>
        <RememberMePeriod>..</RememberMePeriod>
        <CleanUp>
            <Enable>true</Enable>
                <Period>..</Period>
                <TimeOut>..</TimeOut>
        </CleanUp>
        <Temporary>false</Temporary>
    </SessionDataPersist>
```

which is available as part of WSO2 IS SP1 is only applicable when Remember me option is selected? Is there any other config where we manage these session timeouts?

Regards,
Cijoy

Answer (score 0):

If you do not enable the session persistence,  WSO2IS invalidates the SSO session after 15 minutes inactive time and the value is not configurable as it is the cache invalidation time.    WSO2IS 5.0.0  just stores the SSO session in caches which is not correct and which can leads to lot of issues.  Then WSO2IS 5.0.0 SP1 introduces the session persistence. So; currently  there is no configuration to define the session timeout explicitly. But timeout can be happened, when these session can be deleted.

Therefore timeout can be achieve with cleanup task but it is not an inactive time out.

`<CleanUp>
    <Enable>true</Enable>
    <Period>10</Period>
    <TimeOut>60</TimeOut>
</CleanUp>`

`CleanUp.Period` defines the time period among two consecutive cleanups in minutes. By default it is 1 day.`CleanUp.TimeOut` defines the timeout value of session data in minutes. By default it is two weeks.
For an example if we consider the above configuration it means that the clean up task will run periodically with a period of 10 minutes.
And in a cleanup process it will remove all session data persisted before 60 minutes.

Comment: Thanks Asela. Does it mean that there is no need to select the remember me option(login page)  for session data persistence to kick in? I'm bit confused with the remember me option and its intended purpose. Owing to the fact that cleanup task can be used as a timeout rather than inactive timeout, does it mean that my application logout(or any other request referring the session idx)  will fail if it is active for more than time specified for cleanup? My observation is that the logout fails with no longer valid session idx error when doing a logout from the applications after 15min